# One select with multiples counts (very similar), possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, mysqli, mysql-workbench, bdd

I have a dude.

I have a select like this:

```
SELECT 
    ES.id, 
    ES.nombre nombreEstacion, 
    COUNT(LE.id) Cuenta
FROM estacion ES 
    LEFT JOIN lectura LE ON ES.id = LE.idEstacion
    LEFT JOIN tipo_estacion AS TE ON TE.id=ES.idTipoEstacion
WHERE 
    ES.eliminada=0 
    AND LE.resultadoNOK=0 
    OR LE.idEstacion IS NULL
GROUP BY ES.id
```

ID  NAMEESTATION  COUNT

I would like to do a select with this appareance:
ID  NAME  COUNT1 COUNT2 COUNT3 in the same select.

This counts are with the same structure. they only have one diference.

```
count1 is when  (WHERE LE.resultadoNOK=0)
count2 is when  (WHERE LE.resultadoNOK=1)
count3 is when  (WHERE LE.resultadoNOK=3)
```

Some people tell me that the solution is using something like this:
    COUNT(LE.id) Cuenta,
    SUM(IF(X,X,X) COUNT2,
    SUM(IF(X,X,X) COUNT3

but i dont understand this structure and i dont understand what values I have to write in the "IF".

I search about another posibility with "CASE" , buy i dont understant too

Somebody can explain me how works this??

Thanks guys!! :)

Comment: What exactly are you using: sql server or mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do this with SUM and a case expression.

```
SELECT 
    ES.id, 
    ES.nombre nombreEstacion, 
    SUM(case when LE.resultadoNOK = 0 then 1 end) as CuentaUno,
    SUM(case when LE.resultadoNOK = 1 then 1 end) as CuentaDos,
    SUM(case when LE.resultadoNOK = 2 then 1 end) as CuentaTres
FROM estacion ES 
    LEFT JOIN lectura LE ON ES.id = LE.idEstacion
    LEFT JOIN tipo_estacion AS TE ON TE.id=ES.idTipoEstacion
WHERE 
    ES.eliminada=0 
    AND LE.idEstacion IS NULL
GROUP BY ES.id
    , ES.nombre
```

Comment: Oh thanks! tomorrow i taste it!
But this two ways are the same? 

Y have one more dude. what the diference in the code:
GROUP BY ES.id (like i did) 
or 
GROUP BY ES.id, ES.nombre

change something?

Comment: Because you can't group by ONLY eES.id unless nombre is also in an aggregate. Also notice I removed the where predicate that limited your result to only show rows where resultadoNOK = 0? That is kind of required if you want to have multiple values of that showing up.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a **CASE** statement like this:

```
SELECT 
    ES.id, 
    ES.nombre nombreEstacion, 
    COUNT(LE.id) Cuenta,
    SUM(CASE WHEN LE.resultadoNOK = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN LE.resultadoNOK = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN LE.resultadoNOK = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT3
FROM estacion ES 
    LEFT JOIN lectura LE ON ES.id = LE.idEstacion
    LEFT JOIN tipo_estacion AS TE ON TE.id=ES.idTipoEstacion
WHERE 
    ES.eliminada=0 
    AND LE.resultadoNOK=0 
    OR LE.idEstacion IS NULL
GROUP BY ES.id
```

Comment: Oh thanks! tomorrow i taste it!
But this two ways are the same? 

Y have one more dude. what the diference in the code:
GROUP BY ES.id (like i did) 
or 
GROUP BY ES.id, ES.nombre

change something?

Comment: I didn't notice that in the Group By. You would need to include **ES.nombre** in the Group By since it's not aggregated.

Comment: didnt work :((( I test your solution but there are a lot o f register to null. i test with the solution "case when LE.resultadoNOK = 0 then 1 end)" but i think its wrong.

Comment: If your **resultadoNOK can be NULL, I would use `SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(LE.resultadoNOK, -1) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` if you don't want the NULLs to count. This will transform NULL values to -1 so it doesn't match.